# How to do one tap signin and signup in Android

Tags: java, android, google-one-tap

Here is my code which I followed from Google Developers page

```
signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
    .setPasswordRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
        .setSupported(true)
        .build())
    .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
        .setSupported(true)
        // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
        .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.server_id))
        // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
        .build())
    .build();

oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                    result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender(), REQ_ONE_TAP, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
            // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
```

I am implementing one tap signin and signup in my Android application and also I have created a project in Google API console and mentioned the client ID here but the above code is not working.

I have searched example projects but not available and also an example YouTube video for step by step code flow is not available. What can I try next?

Comment: Please post the error log

Comment: sorry i am not getting any errors

Comment: then probably the code is not executed

Comment: please tell me what i have to do

Comment: you should call / debug the method where that code is placed

Comment: i called the method when button is clicked and also i did debug the debug is executing next lines but the list of google accounts which available in my device is not showing

Comment: please define clearly what you want to achieve? where will the user get signup? are you using some server or you want to use google signin or whatever, define clearly.

Comment: Hey did you solve you problem

Answer (score 4):

The log would have helped, although I am guessing this is the Exception:

> No matching credentials found

In the code change

```
.setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
```

to

```
.setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
```